Conversion problem
Welcome ...
I made a transfer from a bitcoin core wallet to another wallet, but the transfer did not arrive from yesterday
hash:
7fd7aac91098b5a5144dae424cd5bc2b3224b695a58c0348a47dca601de3cd41
